# Source Control Shelving

Tags: visual-sourcesafe

We have some new-ish folks that have experience with TFS who are always referring to "shelving."  Unfortunately we are quite far behind the curve and still use Source Safe.  I have searched high and low for such a functionality in source safe and cannot find it.

The closest thing I can think of is to exclude a file from the solution when it is not ready to be checked in at night but I can think of a few things that might go wrong with that, especially when you get latest the next day.

Does anyone have any web references about shelving with source safe?

Comment: VSS doesn't support shelving. And I don't like the "exclude" solution, because this way you may easily lose your modifications. One workaround I can think of (not the perfect one) is creating a branch for your project. When the job is done, you can merge the project to the original one. Another way to solve the problem is getting a VSS replacement. TFS is a good option especially when some of your team members have already used the tool. If TFS is too heavy for you, you can also consider SourceAnywhere Standalone.

Answer (score 0):

That's because it doesn't exist.

Closest thing is you make some changes to the code base on your own machine and then demo/ test them locally. If you get an okay, then you check them in.

If you want shelving, and you should, because it has a lot of uses, I'm afraid you are going to have use something invented this century. :(

Comment: Indeed.  We've been nearly begging them for VS2010 but they don't want us to have it and they won't say why.

Comment: Is bloody expensive, is why. Professional MSDN licenses is better value. VS and TFS is very nice combination. Might want to check about for an open source offering. Bound to be one more upto date with better features than VSS, as it's pretty much dead. NB some offer hosted TFS, sort of thing makes me nervous, but it's out there.

Answer (score 0):

Whilst this is not true Shelving in the TFS sense, you can Label in SS prior to checkin. Then checkin your changes (shelve). Then in SS, View History (Labels Only) and get the old version you labeled.